# spring websocket status:400 websocket connect keep-alive

Tags: spring, websocket, keep-alive, bad-request

I have an issue with connecting to a spring websocket implementation.

After debugging the code, I find that the request header 'Connection' has two values, 'keep-alive' and 'Upgrade' from my simple javascript code.

The fiddler output of the request is :-

```
GET http://localhost:8282/play/stream HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8282
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic bXNhZG1pbjptc2FkbWlu
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: http://localhost:8282
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=8C8748DD08104EAD51296E4A9E846604
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 9edBIn/q4i5pyQOFf72SMA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

...The DefaultHandshakeHandler calls HttpHeaders.getConnection() which returns the FIRST value being 'keep-alive'. This, it compares to 'Upgrade' and 'upgrade' and fails.

What is the problem here? Is the keep-alive header allowed in this situation, and if so, is the logic incorrect?

I am using spring-websockets/spring-web 4.0.8.RELEASE

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is technically correct as HTTP 1.1 accepts multiple fields with the same field-name (RFC2616 section 4.2). However, [HttpHeaders](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.java) will only take the first value, that's the reason. Remove the first *Connection* header or
reorder them so *Connection: Upgrade* is picked.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! This must be a bug in spring-websockets as it is not expecting the keep-alive header and only takes the first value.